# Why are lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ all congruent to one another, but circles in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are not?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, differential-geometry, group-actions, homogeneous-spaces

Lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are all congruent to one another, but circles in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are not all congruent to one another (because two different circles may have different radii).  Visually, this is completely obvious.  However, I would like a **group-theoretic** explanation for this.

> I am thinking of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the homogeneous space $\mathbb{R}^3 = \frac{G}{G_0} = \frac{\text{SE}(3)}{\text{SO}(3)}$, where $G = \text{SE}(3)$ is the group of (orientation-preserving) rigid motions and $G_0 = \text{SO}(3)$ is the stabilizer of the origin.
>
> A **line in $\mathbb{R}^3$** is an orbit of a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by a subgroup $H \leq G$ that is conjugate to the subgroup $\{ (x_1, x_2, x_3) \mapsto (x_1 + t, x_2, x_3) \colon t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ of translations by the vector $(1,0,0)$.
>
> A **circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$** is an orbit of a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by a subgroup $K \leq G$ that is conjugate to the subgroup $\{ (x_1 + ix_2, x_3) \mapsto (e^{i\theta}(x_1 + ix_2), x_3) \colon e^{i\theta} \in \mathbb{S}^1\}$ of rotations around the $x_3$-axis.
>
> Two subsets $S_1, S_2$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are **congruent** if there exists $g \in \text{SE}(3)$ such that $S_2 = g \cdot S_1$.

Given these definitions of "line" and "circle" --- as orbits of subgroups --- how could we have known that all lines in $\text{SE}(3)/\text{SO}(3)$ are congruent, but not all circles in $\text{SE}(3)/\text{SO}(3)$ have this property?

In other words: What are the relevant aspects of the subgroups $H$, $K$, and $G_0$ that explain the $G$-equivalence of $H$-orbits in $G/G_0$, as opposed to the non-$G$-equivalence of all $K$-orbits in $G/G_0$?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the general group-theoretic setup.  Let $G$ be a group and $G_0,H\subset G$ be subgroups.  An orbit of $H$ in $G/G_0$ can be considered as a double coset $HxG_0\subseteq G$.  Let $S$ be the set of all orbits of conjugates of $H$ in $G/G_0$.  Then $G$ acts on $S$ by left translation, since $g\cdot HxG_0=(gHg^{-1})gxG_0$ is a double coset for the conjugate $gHg^{-1}$.

I don't think there's any nice necessary and sufficient characterization of when $G$ acts transitively on $S$, but there are a couple simple special cases that are enough to answer your question about lines and circles.

First, suppose $H\subseteq G_0$ but some conjugate $x^{-1}Hx$ of $H$ is not contained in $G_0$.  (This is true when $H$ is your $K$.)  Then one element of $S$ is $HG_0=G_0$ and another is $HxG_0$.  If $G$ acted transitively on $S$ there would be some $g\in G$ such that $gG_0=HxG_0$; that is, $HxG_0$ would be a left coset of $G_0$.  Since $x\in HxG_0$, it would be the left coset of $x$ so $xG_0=HxG_0$.  This implies $G_0=x^{-1}HxG_0$, but that is not true by assumption since $x^{-1}Hx\not\subseteq G_0$.  Thus $G$ cannot act transitively on $S$.

(Interestingly, in the context of circles, this argument makes crucial use of a degenerate circle of radius $0$, which is what the double coset $HG_0=G_0$ represents.  In geometric terms, it is saying that since your group $K$ fixes one point but does not fix all points, there is a circle with just one point and a circle with more than one point, and they cannot be congruent.)

Now suppose that $N(H)G_0=G$.  (This is true for your line group $H$, since every translation normalizes $H$ and every rigid transformation is a composition of a rotation around the origin and a translation.)  Consider any double coset $H'xG_0\in S$ for some $H'$ conjugate to $H$; we wish to show $H'xG_0$ is in the orbit of $HG_0$, so $G$ acts transitively on $S$.  If $H'=gHg^{-1}$ we can first multiply $H'xG_0$ by $g^{-1}$ to assume that $H'=H$.  Now by hypothesis, we can write $x=ng$ for some $n\in N(H)$ and $g\in G_0$.  We then have $$HxG_0=HngG_0=HnG_0=nHG_0$$ so $HxG_0$ is indeed in the orbit of $HG_0$.

(Note that you might try and reverse this argument to prove that $N(H)G_0=G$ is actually necessary and sufficient for $G$ to act transitively on $S$.  Indeed, there exists $n\in N(H)$ such that $HxG_0=nHG_0$ iff $x\in N(H)G_0$.  However, this isn't quite enough to prove necessity, since you could have $HxG_0=yHG_0$ for some $y\in G$ that is not in $N(H)$, and I don't know any particularly nice way of describing when that happens.  Note here that given an element of $S$, the conjugate of $H$ for which it is a double coset is not necessarily unique.  See [Normalizer of group action](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3259196/normalizer-of-group-action) for some related discussion, and in particular the example at the end of Morgan Rodgers's answer which is one where $G$ acts transitively on $S$ but $N(H)G_0\neq G$.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but an enlargment of its scope.

There exists a group which is transitive on the union of lines and circles : it is the **anallagmatic group**, existing in any dimension. I mention it in the third paragraph of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2626356) and in particular i give a linear representation through generators that can be helpful for obtaining for example, given two 3D circles, the operation that will map the one onto the other.